# ubuntu 13.04 - Some radeon firmware files missing - low resolution problem

Tags: 13.04, ati, kernel, resolution, mesa

I have a MSI HD6870 video card and I'm using open source drivers.
I have upgraded from kernel 3.8 to 3.11.0-031100 stable.

After reboot I had low resolution problem, that is my maximum resolution is 1920x1080 but I can set and see only 1280x1024 as maximum resolution.

I already had solved this problem removing the `nomodeset` option from `/etc/default/grub` when using kernel 3.8. So I decided to install kernel 3.11 and the low resolution problem came back. It's strange because the grub still has no `nomodeset` option now.

I noticed that I have some radeon firmware files missing in kernel 3.11 that in kernel 3.8 was not, therefore I found this bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/+bug/1183777.

They say that it has been solved with `linux-firmware` package v1.113 but I have `linux-firmware 1.106` so maybe it's due to kernel 3.11 has been released for ubuntu 13.10 and I have 13.04,

so how can I solve this firmware files missing?

I'm assuming that the radeon firmware files missing is related to my resolution problem, but I'm not sure so please tell me if I'm wrong, if so how can I solve the resolution problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem after upgradeing to 13.10 on a AMD HD4650 and the OS radeon drivers. (amds drivers didn't work after upgrade to kernel 3.11 and I wanted to get rid of them anyway)

After reading your post, I just reinstalled linux-firmware:

```
apt-get install --reinstall linux-firmware
```

It installed 1.116

This resolved it for me.